# one is to many relationship, getting latest row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

```
lead_sp_id  sp_id   phone
1           5       111     
2           5       222     
3           5       333 
4           3       444     
5           3       555     
6           3       666     
7           3       777 
8           5       888 

act_id      lead_sp_id sp_id   act_time
1           1          5       2012-12-31 14:20:49      
2           1          5       2012-12-30 14:20:49      
3           2          5       2012-12-29 14:20:49  
4           2          5       2012-12-31 14:20:49  
5           2          5       2012-12-28 14:20:49   
6           4          3       2012-12-31 14:20:49  
7           4          3       2012-12-28 14:20:49  
8           4          3       2012-12-25 14:20:49
```

result I would like to get is

```
phone | lead_sp_id | sp_id | act_time
111   | 1          | 5     | 2012-12-31 14:20:49
222   | 2          | 5     | 2012-12-31 14:20:49
```

Now I know I have to use a join statement and using the regular join statement just gives me too many result including the old dates all I am looking to to do is to get the latest act_name and act_time for each phone number based on the sp_id.

Comment: share your query and define your problem clearly

Comment: what have you done here with this tables? Explanation would be good!

Comment: just to let you know i have always accepted the right answers ....also couple of questions i have asked no one has answered os i am not sure how that affects the rows. ...

Comment: Give and take is healthier friendlier... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.phone, b.lead_sp_id, b.sp_id, b.act_time 
FROM leadsptable a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.lead_sp_id, a.sp_id, a.act_time 
            FROM acttable a 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT lead_sp_id, MAX(act_time) act_time 
                        FROM acttable GROUP BY lead_sp_id
                      ) b ON a.lead_sp_id = b.lead_sp_id AND a.act_time = b.act_time 
            ) b ON a.lead_sp_id = b.lead_sp_id AND a.sp_id = b.sp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM 
            table2      
            INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(act_id) FROM table2 GROUP BY act_id) 
            as r on r.act_id = table2.act_id
) as t2 on t1.sp_id = t2.sp_id
```